# How to Point & click an object in JS / JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am currently coding a pipeline WebApp in JS/JQuery.
To move my block I use JQuery.draggable. But I would like to be able to select my block with one click and to move it to an other point just by an other click.

Has anyone already done this?

Have a great day! :)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. In particular, explain what "point and click" means. That's basically how all of the internet works.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Drag and Drop is not good for this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  function moveItemTo(t) {
    $(".selected").detach().removeClass("selected ui-state-highlight").appendTo(t);
  }

  $(".item").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("selected ui-state-highlight");
  });

  $(".target").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
    moveItemTo(this);
  });
})
```

```css
.item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
}

.target {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0.5em;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}

.selected {
  opacity: 0.65;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
  <div class="item ui-widget-content">
    <p>1. Click Me</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item ui-widget-content">
    <p>2. Click Me</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item ui-widget-content">
    <p>3. Click Me</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item ui-widget-content">
    <p>4. Click Me</p>
  </div>
  <div class="item ui-widget-content">
    <p>5. Click Me</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="target ui-widget-header">
    <p>Target 1</p>
  </div>

  <div class="target ui-widget-header">
    <p>Target 2</p>
  </div>

  <div class="target ui-widget-header">
    <p>Target 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This does not use any of the jQuery UI, except for CSS. Clicking an Item selects it. Clicking a Target Moves it to that target.

Comment: Hello, where "selected ui-state-highlight" comes from?

Comment: Hello, when I tried it on VS Code it didn't work, is there anything special to add?